# append digits after decimal

Tags: regex, alteryx

I have a following digits and would like to use a regex to convert to the following , can some one point me in the right direction.

```
Current State   Desired State 
        13.2    13.29999
        1.66    1.66999
        1.002   1.00299
        0.2336  0.23369
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you determining how many `9`s to add? Have you tried any regexs yet? I'd guess `(\.\d+?)(\D)` then append `9`s between `$1` and `$2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a regular expression, but an Alteryx solution: use a Formula tool with the following expression:

```
ToNumber(
IF Contains(ToString(f1),".") THEN
   PadRight(ToString([f1]),Length(ToString([f1],5)),"9") 
ELSE
   ToString([f1]) + ".99999" 
ENDIF
)
```

This assumes field `[f1]` is numeric and will work for integers. If `[f1]` is guaranteed to always have a decimal (as in your examples), then you need not have the `If` and could simply run with:

```
ToNumber(
   PadRight(ToString([f1]),Length(ToString([f1],5)),"9") 
)
```

Explanation: If it's an integer (there is no decimal point), then simply append the decimal and five 9's... if it does contain a decimal, then Alteryx provides a `ToString([f1],5)` which pads zeroes to five decimal points. But you want nines so instead I just grab the length of this, and PadRight the original `[f1]` with 9's to the same length.